# Why does changing StringBuilder change its hashCode?

Tags: java, stringbuilder, hashcode

this is input.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("hello");
        printBuilder(builder);

        // append
        builder.append(" everyone");
        printBuilder(builder);

        builder.append(", what's up?");
        printBuilder(builder);
    }

    private static void printBuilder(StringBuilder dataBuild){
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(dataBuild);
    System.out.println("data = " + build);
    System.out.println("length = " + build.length());
    System.out.println("capacity = " + build.capacity());
    int addressBuild = System.identityHashCode(build);
    System.out.println("address = " + Integer.toHexString(addressBuild);
    }
```

this is output.

- data = hello
- length = 25
- capacity = 21
- address = 5b480cf9
- data = hello everyone
- length = 14
- capacity = 30
- address = 6f496d9f
- data = hello everyone, what's up?
- length = 26
- capacity = 42
- address = 723279cf

why the address different from other?
i though will be the same. i tried different like insert, replace, charAt, but still the address was different. can anyone tell me why?.

Comment: Yea.  The reason the hashcode changes is that you are explicitly creating a new `StringBuilder` in `printBuilder` each time that you call it.  Look at your code carefully.

Comment: One clarification: The `hashCode` is **not** the address of an object. The default implementation (if the class did not override the method) **may** be based on the address or other factors, but that is about it.

Comment: _i though will be the same_ Can you clarify why you thought so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `printBuild()`, you make a new `StringBuilder` with every call. The hash is printed for the new builder every time:

```
int addressBuild = System.identityHashCode(build);
```

You can't reasonably expect a different result. If you want to see the same hash every time, remove the following line:

```
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(dataBuild);
```

Operate on the input argument `dataBuild` directly: it's passed in as a reference.

To elaborate: [`System.identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) produces a result that is only guaranteed to be identical if the objects are the same (as in `==`, not `equals()`). If course, as with any hash, two unequal objects may have the same hash, but the function does try to reduce overlap. As expected, the result is often *based* on memory location, although it generally isn't the memory location itself.

Answer (score 0):

[`System#identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) does not return the address of the object.

> Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned
> by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's
> class overrides hashCode(). The hash code for the null reference is
> zero.

Each object of a class has a different hash code. Since you are creating a new object with each call to `printBuilder`, you are getting a different hash code.

**Note:** The comparison using `==` returns `true` for the references having equal hash codes.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean b1 = true;
        Boolean b2 = Boolean.valueOf("true");
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b1));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b2));
        System.out.println(b1 == b2);

        String s1 = "Hello";
        String s2 = s1;
        String s3 = new String("Hello");// Creates a new object and hence s3 will have a different hash code
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s1));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s2));
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s3));
        System.out.println(s2 == s3);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
992136656
992136656
true
511833308
511833308
true
1297685781
false
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's the address or not: what matters is that OP is making a new object every time

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Where did I say that it is an address?

Comment: You said it's not, implying that that is somehow relevant to the question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I stand by my statement, `System#identityHashCode does not return the address of the object.`.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you at all. It really and truly doesn't return the address. But the requirement for a good answer is that it be true and address the question. You post only fulfills the former in my opinion.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I have added one more sentence in my answer to make it clearer.